# camera slider, nivo lightbox - jQuery conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, lightbox

I have a problem when I using slider and nivo lightbox together in one php file.
Ok, I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slider/jquerySlider.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slider/jquery.mobile.customized.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slider/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slider/camera.min.js"></script> 

<script>
    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery('#camera_wrap_1').camera({
            thumbnails: false,
            loader: 'bar',
            pagination: false,
            height: '300px',
        });
    });
</script>

<!--Nivo LightBox-->    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nivo-lightbox.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/default/default.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/nivoLightbox/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/nivoLightbox/nivo-lightbox.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a').nivoLightbox();
    });
</script>
```

Now it's working only Nivo Lightbox, slider doesn't work. If I delete row with
src="js/nivoLightbox/jquery.min.js, slider now working and the lightbox doesn't.

I think that jQuerySlider.min.js is another version of jquery.min.js. In general, all two scripts are some versions of jQuery library. When I both delete and replaced it one, the newest, it still doesn't work.

Please can anyone rewrite this code to working solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can find your solution below..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slider/jquery.mobile.customized.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slider/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slider/camera.min.js"></script> 


<!--Nivo LightBox-->    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nivo-lightbox.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/default/default.css" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/nivoLightbox/nivo-lightbox.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#camera_wrap_1').camera({
            thumbnails: false,
            loader: 'bar',
            pagination: false,
            height: '300px',
        });

        $('a').nivoLightbox();
    });
</script>
```